# Lila's sea map / pirate map in Grey London

Tags: shades-of-magic

Lila's sea map. She has it in Grey London before meeting Kell. It comes in handy later because it takes them to Maris' secret floating market. But how would a one get a sea map in Grey London?

It seems unlikely that it came from Powell, the drunk owner of the Sea King, who would ramble about

> Stories of lands he'd never visited. Maidens he'd never wooded. Treasures he'd never plundered.

So assuming she stole it from a shop or somewhere, could it have come from Kell? Or is there another way that someone like Fletcher could have traveled into Grey London with it?